# common attributes not showing for TextView in android studio

Tags: android-studio

**I can't see the 'common attributes' tab in the Attributes section.**

I'm following an android studio tutorial. On the teacher's screen, there is the 'common attributes' tab in the Attributes section. But there are no common attributes in mine.

The following image is a screenshot of my android studio.

[image: img]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with you on android API 33.

Changing your android SDK version to API 31(Android 12.0) will help you.

1. Go to setting. (Ctrl + Alt + S)
2. Search 'SDK' and find 'Android SDK' in System Settings
3. Uninstall(remove checkbox) API 33 and apply.
4. Install Android 12.0(API 31) and apply.
5. Restart project.

[Android SDK settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkci0.png)

[After changing version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p93X.png)