# Android studio not showing textSize attribute for TextView

Tags: android-studio

I've just began a tutorial to learn Kotlin Development but I realised that, when I select a TextView component, I don't have access to the textSize attribute, nor the common attribute section as we can see on the picture.

[image]

I've seen [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944312/common-attributes-not-showing-for-textview-in-android-studio) already but it wasn't the solution for me. Also, the textSize attribute doesn't appear in the All Attributes section.

As a beginner, I come here to ask you if you have any idea :)

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the elements there.

Check out this image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it appeared there after an update !